# Newline ignored in mailto:

Tags: javascript, email

I am have items added to a 'cart' which is just a `div`. When I add them I add a `<br />` to the end to make things look tidy. When it's done the user can hit a link and the contents of the `div` is set in the link. When the email opens all the items are joined together with no newline, so figured I need to replace the `<br />` with a `\n` but this is being ignored also.

```
   function br2nl(str) {
        return str.replace(/<br\s*\/?>/mg,"\n");
    }      

  function addtocart(part)
 {
 $('#cart').append(part + '<br />'); 
 var body = br2nl($('#cart').html());
 $('#maillink').attr("href","mailto:?subject=Parts&body=" + body)
 }
```

Comment: Which mail client are you testing this with?

Comment: This particular pc has thunderbird

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mailto` function will fail with HTML.
Use plain text.

Newline characters can be included using it's url encoded equivalent `%0D`.

Comment: solution in the end was %0D%0A put pointed in the right direction